# Append Index to Duplicate Pairs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of transactions that contain a header (H) and detail (D) row for each transaction. There is an Invoice Number column that must match for the H and D rows, but sometimes there are duplicates of that Invoice Number if there are several transactions on the same day. What I would like to do is add an index to the end of the Invoice Number for any duplicates. See below for a visual representation of my data frame and what I am trying to accomplish. I have used letters as the index in the example to help see the difference but a number index would work too, just trying to eliminate duplicate naming.

I'm not sure if I have to iterate over each record or if there is something that can be done as a whole.

**Original File**

| ID | type | invoice number | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | H | BOB12192022 | 10.00 |
| 01 | D | BOB12192022 | 10.00 |
| 02 | H | JOE12182022 | 30.00 |
| 02 | D | JOE12182022 | 30.00 |
| 03 | H | BOB12192022 | 15.00 |
| 03 | D | BOB12192022 | 15.00 |
| 04 | H | BOB12192022 | 75.00 |
| 04 | D | BOB12192022 | 25.00 |
| 04 | D | BOB12192022 | 25.00 |
| 04 | D | BOB12192022 | 25.00 |

**Expected Result**

| ID | type | invoice number | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | H | BOB12192022A | 10.00 |
| 01 | D | BOB12192022A | 10.00 |
| 02 | H | JOE12182022 | 30.00 |
| 02 | D | JOE12182022 | 30.00 |
| 03 | H | BOB12192022B | 15.00 |
| 03 | D | BOB12192022B | 15.00 |
| 04 | H | BOB12192022C | 75.00 |
| 04 | D | BOB12192022C | 25.00 |
| 04 | D | BOB12192022C | 25.00 |
| 04 | D | BOB12192022C | 25.00 |

Comment: Can I make a suggestion? Adding a column indicating a `duplicate` with the order will be much easier for you to handle the later calculations.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a column indicating a duplicated. It will be much easier. Otherwise there will be a trouble when tracing back the name for calculation

```
df['dup'] = df.groupby(['type, invoice_number'])['invoice_number'].cumcount()
```

You can easily identify any `invoice` is duplicated if `dup` value is **not** `0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby.transform()` with a bit of arithmetic and integer-to-character conversion:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "type": ["H", "D", "H", "D", "H", "D"],
        "invoice": ["ABC", "ABC", "DEF", "DEF", "ABC", "ABC"],
        "amount": ["10", "10", "20", "20", "10", "10"],
    }
)

df["suffix"] = df.groupby("invoice")["type"].transform(
    lambda x: ["_" + chr(65 + int(np.floor(i / 2))) for i in range(len(x))]
)
df["invoice"] = df["invoice"] + df["suffix"]
```

Result:

```
  type invoice amount suffix
0    H   ABC_A     10     _A
1    D   ABC_A     10     _A
2    H   DEF_A     20     _A
3    D   DEF_A     20     _A
4    H   ABC_B     10     _B
5    D   ABC_B     10     _B
```

Note this approach assumes you have 2 entries per transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

```
df['invoice number'] = (df['invoice number'] + 
                        (df[df.duplicated(['type', 'invoice number'], keep=False)].groupby('ID').ngroup())
                              .map(dict(enumerate(ascii_uppercase)))).fillna(df['invoice number'])
```

Output:

```
   ID type invoice number  amount
0   1    H   BOB12192022A    10.0
1   1    D   BOB12192022A    10.0
2   2    H    JOE12182022    30.0
3   2    D    JOE12182022    30.0
4   3    H   BOB12192022B    15.0
5   3    D   BOB12192022B    15.0
6   4    H   BOB12192022C    75.0
7   4    D   BOB12192022C    25.0
8   4    D   BOB12192022C    25.0
9   4    D   BOB12192022C    25.0
```

Try this:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

df['invoice number'] += np.where(df.groupby(['invoice number'])['invoice number'].transform('count') > 2,
                                 df.groupby(['type', 'invoice number']).cumcount().map(dict(enumerate(ascii_uppercase))), '')
```

Output:

```
  type invoice number  amount
0    H   BOB12192022A    10.0
1    D   BOB12192022A    10.0
2    H    JOE12182022    30.0
3    D    JOE12182022    30.0
4    H   BOB12192022B    15.0
5    D   BOB12192022B    15.0
6    H   BOB12192022C    50.0
7    D   BOB12192022C    50.0
```

Comment: This is very close to what I need, in fact it does what was outlined but in testing with the actual file I found that I have a couple records where there is more than one 'D' record per 'H' record. In that instance it continues to index up through the alphabet.

Comment: Is there a way to make all 'D' records maintain the same letter as the the 'H' record preceding it?

Comment: @bradsdb  Can you alter your input dataframe about to account for your discrepancy and show expected output?

Comment: Yes, just updated it to show an example. However, there can be many more 'D' records. It represents a split transaction.

Comment: I made one additional edit that may be helpful, each of the transactions has an ID that ties them all together.

Comment: @bradsdb I am sure, there will be another edge case you need to handle.

Comment: Thanks @Scott, I think something is not quite working correctly. It does append the letter to the end of the duplicates, however, it appears to not reset anymore. Meaning that it instead of two different dates both having A at the end the 2nd one gets B then C and so on. Also, the 'H' row appears to be missing the appended letter, so it looks like the below:

H  BOB12192022    75
D  BOB12192022C  25
D  BOB12192022C  25
D  BOB12192022C  25